# Converting forks into pthreads

Tags: c, linux, pthreads, fork

Is there anyway i can convert this code to use Posix (p) threads rather than forks? I have to experiment on the differences between the two in memory and processing power. I am testing the effects of a different number of processes on the CPU% of a processor depending on the number of cores.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <stdlib.h> 
#include <math.h> 

#define N 16 /* define the total number of processes we want */ 

float total=0; 

int compute() 
{ 
 int i; 
 float oldtotal=0, result=0; 

 the arbitrary number 1000 */ 

 for(i=0;i<2000000000;i++) 
 { 
 result=sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(1000.0); 
 }  
 /* Print the result \u2013 should be no surprise */ 
 printf("Result is %f\n",result); 

 oldtotal = total; 
 total = oldtotal + result; 

 /* Print running total so far. */ 
 printf("Total is %f\n",total); 

 return(0); 
} 


int main() 
{ 
 int pid[N], i, j; 
 float result=0; 

 printf("\n");  


 for(i=0;i<N;i++) 
 { 
 if((pid[i]=fork())==-1) 
 { 
 exit(1); 
 } 
 else if(pid[i] > 0) 
 { 
 /* give a message about the proc ID */ 
 printf("Process Id for process %d is %d\n",i,getpid()); 

 /* call the function to do some computation. */ 
 compute(); 

 break; 
 } 
 } 
 return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Did you try anything? First you have to start creating threads with pthread_create().

Comment: It seems odd that the parent process does the computation, rather than the children - so there's a weird process structure in effect.  Note that the forked processes are not sharing the global variable `total` once the child is forked.  In the threaded code, you'd have to provide access control (a mutex) to protect the global variable `total`.  Otherwise, it doesn't look to be too difficult.

Comment: With optimization turned on when compiling e.g. with `gcc -O2` the `for(i=0;i<2000000000;i++) result=sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(1000.0);` will be removed. Try computing something significant, perhaps `for(i=0;i<2000000000;i++) result=sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(result+0.1);`

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
#include <pthread.h>

void *cback(void *void_ptr) 
{

 int i;   
 float oldtotal=0, result=0; 


 for(i=0;i<2000000000;i++)   
 { 
     result=sqrt(1000.0)*sqrt(1000.0);  
 }   
 printf("Result is %f\n",result); 

 oldtotal = total;   total = oldtotal + result; 

 printf("x increment finished\n");

 return NULL;

}

int main () 
{  
pthread_t onethread;

if (pthread_create(&onethread, NULL, cback, NULL) != 0)
{
   printf("error creating thread\n");
}

}
```

See [man page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_create.3.html) and [tutorial](http://www.cs.kent.edu/~ruttan/sysprog/lectures/multi-thread/multi-thread.html)

Comment: So what is this doing exactly? I can compile the code using `gcc -o 4test 4test.o -lm -static -pthread` but there is no output when running it.